Textbook on cohomology on sites
I already asked this a while ago, but now I can make the question more precise.
I'm looking for a textbook in cohomology on sites that includes Lemma 21.10.6 on the Stacks Project.
I don't think that one can learn about cohomology on sites using the Stacks Project as a textbook, and the one and only textbook that I found which treats the subject is Tamme's Introduction to Etale Cohomology; however I think Tamme just wanted to give a summary in the first chapters, making clear the point of view and proving some specific results for later, in order to introduce etale cohomology.
I would need instead an introduction to cohomology on sites, that does not treat the subject as already known. I hope that I have been more precise this time, thanks for any suggestion.

How exactly is Tamme's book not sufficient? I learned cohomology on sites via this book. And how exactly is the Stacks Project not sufficient? What is missing, precisely?

@MartinBrandenburg Regarding Stacks Project: what I need to learn for my course is basically sections 21.8,9,10 in SP. However to understand those I need a bit of context so I start from the beginning, section 21.2. Here I read to take an injective resolution $F[0]\to I^\bullet$, where $F$ is an abelian sheaf. What does this mean, that $I\bullet$ is a chain complex of abelian sheaves?

If you have a doubt on notations the size of SP doesn't make it easy to find it. Then the sections 21.3-7 are mainly material that I shouldn't deal with, so in the end I find myself starting from 21.8 and going continuously back looking for definitions that are not even in chapter 21 sometimes. I would like a more linear text, which gives me what I need to know for an introduction, instead of treating many things from the beginning because they will be needed later

Tamme is quite good for me too indeed, even if a big part of the material is not needed in my course, it's still easier to make a selection on this book than on SP. However if there was a book that treats less material and in a less concise way than Tamme I would certainly give it look
